# Something I don't understand about selecting chips from a set of 5 red chips, 5 green chips and 5 blue chips.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Suppose I am to draw 4 chips from a bag of containing 10 red chips, 10 green and 10 blue. I want to compute the total number of possible outcomes. Let $\Omega$ be the set of oucomes. Of course, the first thing that comes to  mind is that $$|\Omega|=\binom{30}{4}=27405.$$
But then looking at the formal definition [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination):

> A $k$-combination of a set $S$ is a subset of $k$ $\textit{distinct}$
>   elements of $S$. If the set has $n$ elements, the number of
>   $k$-combinations is equal to $\binom{n}{k}.$

So in my case, I am constructing a 4-combination my chips of a set of 30 elements. But the the problem is that I cannot distinguish between chips of the same color. In other words, if I draw any two red chips $RR$ from the entire collection of 10 red chips, then I cannot distinguish them. So am I not overcounting when using combination?

Also since I have the same number of red, green and blue, isn't the bars and stars problem with 4 stars and 3 bars more reasonable? Ie 
$$|\Omega|=\binom{6}{2}=15,$$
which corresponds to 
$$\Omega=\{RRRR,RRRB,RRRG,RRBB, RRGB, RRGG, RBBB, RBBG, RBGG, RGGG, GGGG, GGGB, GGBB, GBBB, BBBB \} ?$$

Comment: For any reasonable model of drawing 4 chips from your bag, the 15 outcomes listed at the end are not equally likely (e.g. RRRR is a lot less likely than RBGG under uniform independent draws), so the (correct) count of 15 distinguishable multi-set outcomes  is mostly irrelevant for simple probability computations about the chips you might pick.

Comment: Your comment to an answer of how to compute the probability of each outcome implies the question *wasn't* how many outcomes there are. It is true that stars and bars give you 15 possible outcomes but they are not equally likely and there is actually little point in figuring out how many outcomes but how many ways where we *distinguish* the chips there are for each outcome.

Comment: In other words, everything you post is absolutely correct and answers the question you state.  But it probably *wasn't* the question asked and your answer, as Ned puts it, is mostly irrelevant.

Comment: " But the the problem is that I cannot distinguish between chips of the same color." Which you *need* to be able to do if you are calculating probabilities. If you draw $3$ red chips and $1$ green chips there is more than one way to do it because you *are* distinguish ${4\choose 3}$ possible red chips from $5$ *distinguishable* red chips. There are ${4\choose 3}{5\choose  1}$ ways to get $3$ red and a green out of ${30\choose 4}$ ways to get any five *distinct* chips for a probability of $\frac {20}{27405}$ to draw $RRRG$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, in the first case you are considering the chips to be all different from each other. Something like you have the chips from 1 to 10 to be red, but in this way you are considering the outcome 1-2-3-4 to be different from the outcome 5-6-7-8, even though in both cases there are only red chips.
But it is not because you have the same ammont of red, green and blue chips that you get 15 possible outcomes.
Suppose you have 10 red chips, 15 green and 100 blue ones? Would it change the outcome?
On the other hand, what if you have only 3 of each chips, would that still hold? How would you possibly get 4 red chips?
In computing possible outcomes all that matters is what is possible, like my example with 10 red, 15 green and 100 blue, you are not concerned with probability. So for the bars and stars to work you just need to make sure that all these outcomes are, in fact, possible.

Comment: But then how would I compute the probability of each such outcome?

Comment: Suppose you want to compute the probability that you get 2 red and 2 blue chips. Lets first see how can it happen, considering the order. The possibilities are RRBB - RBRB - RBBR - BBRR - BRBR - BRRB. For RRBB, for example, you have a probability of $\frac{10}{30} \times \frac{9}{29} \times \frac{10}{28} \times \frac{9}{27}$. Now you can do it for the other possibilities and sum them all toghether to get the result. For probabilities, you will to diferentiate all these cases because they are not equally likely to happen. Things would be different if after you draw a chip you would put it back.